# Cocoon JS Canvas Scaling

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, cocoonjs

I have made a small HTML 5 `canvas` application with fixed size of **640*480**. Code is written considering **640*480** `canvas` (say to paint text or to draw image - fixed coordinates have been used).

Everything is working fine in ipad mini i.e. scaling and touch coordinates.

But scaling is a problem in Android. I have referred CocoonJS Demo List as well. They have specifically set **`margin:0px`** for android.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <style type="text/css">body { margin: 0px; }</style> <!-- Android fix -->
</head>
<body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used code like this in `render()` function

```
context.font = '20pt Calibri';
context.fillStyle = 'rgb(250,130,50)';
context.fillText("Score : "+score,canvas.width-150,30);
```

Score here does not display correctly as expected.

Referred CocoonJs documentation they said to follow this notation :

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width= 640;
canvas.height= 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
ctx= canvas.getContext("2d", {antialias : true });
```

Can anybody suggest something or give direction so that it scales properly?

Answer (score 0):

For now on, the correct way of getting screen size is

```js
window.innerWidth
```

and

```js
window.innerHeight
```

To make your Canvas objects full screen, set

```js
canvas.width= window.innerWidth; canvas.height= window.innerHeight
```

[CocoonJS a survival guide](http://blog.ludei.com/cocoonjs-a-survival-guide/)